# Unable to display address using reverse Geocoding

Tags: android

This is my code......

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            TextView myLatitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mylatitude);
            TextView myLongitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mylongitude);
            TextView myAddress = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myaddress);

            myLatitude.setText("Latitude: " + String.valueOf(LATITUDE));
            myLongitude.setText("Longitude: " + String.valueOf(LONGITUDE));

            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

            try {
                //List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);
                /* List<Address> addresses = new Geocoder(this,Locale.getDefault()).getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);

                if(addresses != null) {
                    Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                    StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("Address:\n");
                    for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                        strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                    }
                    myAddress.setText(strReturnedAddress.toString());*/

                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1); 
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
                if (addresses.size() > 0) { 
                   Address address = addresses.get(0); 

                   for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) 
                      addr=address.getAddressLine(i); 
                }
                else{
                    myAddress.setText("No Address returned!");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                /*e.printStackTrace();
                myAddress.setText("Canont get Address!");*/
            }

        }
```

Can anyone sort out what is the problem???
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have not even stated your problem. Whats the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            TextView myLatitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mylatitude);
            TextView myLongitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mylongitude);
            TextView myAddress = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myaddress);

            myLatitude.setText("Latitude: " + String.valueOf(LATITUDE));
            myLongitude.setText("Longitude: " + String.valueOf(LONGITUDE));

            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

            try {
                //List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);
                /* List<Address> addresses = new Geocoder(this,Locale.getDefault()).getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);

                if(addresses != null) {
                    Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                    StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("Address:\n");
                    for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                        strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                    }
                    myAddress.setText(strReturnedAddress.toString());*/

                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1); 
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
                if (addresses.size() > 0) { 
                   Address address = addresses.get(0); 

                   for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) 
                      sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)+ ",");

                }
                else{
                    myAddress.setText("No Address returned!");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                /*e.printStackTrace();
                myAddress.setText("Canont get Address!");*/
            }
                  myAddress.setText(sb.toString());
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps you could comment / highlight what you've changed and why it fixes the problem...

Comment: and try with Emulator of Google API

Comment: Sorry, my point was that an answer consisting purely of a large block of code, that at first glance looks identical to that in the question is a not a *good* answer and doesn't encourage people to upvote it.  I'm was trying to suggest that you could improve your answer by making it clear what you've changed and why, in the answer.  Thus making it more useful to others and possibly earning you upvotes.  Obviously you're free to ignore the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you should first check the presence of GeoCoder implementation and only then use it. It is not necessarily present in all devices.

> The Geocoder class requires a backend
>   service that is not included in the
>   core android framework. The Geocoder
>   query methods will return an empty
>   list if there no backend service in
>   the platform. Use the isPresent()
>   method to determine whether a Geocoder
>   implementation exists.